# First Big Bang Theory episode with none of the guys in pre-credit sequence

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

I was watching *The Misinterpretation Agitation* (season 8, episode 7) of *The Big Bang Theory* the other evening, and noted that the pre-opening credit sequence was centered around Penny, Bernadette & Amy, with none of Raj, Howard, Leonard, or Sheldon present. It seemed a nice change to kick the show off with the female talent.

It got me to wondering though, is that the *first* episode of BBT to do that? I checked the [IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3823244/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt) for that episode and there was no mention that it was the first. Was there an earlier episode that excluded the guys from the pre-credit sequence?

Comment: http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/ has a list of all episodes and transcripts (or links to transcripts) of many of the episodes. You might try looking through these?

Comment: Season 6, episode 2: 'The Decoupling Fluctuation' definitely beats it, though I'll hold off posting an answer until I'm sure it's the first.

Comment: Any particular reason for rolling back a clean-up edit? Was there a special reason you were misusing a colon and couldn't use full words in the question title?

Comment: @T.J.L. The major reason for the roll-back was that the question was in the body and didn't need repeating in the title. I see no reason for using complete words in the title, as long as the intention is clear. I also like to keep titles shorter, rather than longer. Further, it is not correct punctuation to put a ',' before 'or'. The only other change (the apostrophe) I'm less sure about, but given it was a 1 character change to an otherwise less than optimal edit (IMO) I was confident the original should remain. Thanks for making me type more chars justifying the rll-bck than wr in the edit.

Answer (score -5):

I think it was the first episode of that kind and it should be duly noted that this was around the time of women empowerment was picking up. Chuck Lorre has expressed his respect for females in many interviews and I think this was a gesture to show his respect by excluding the other characters.

Comment: The answering part here is very short and borderline not an answer. Do you have any further evidence (reviewed a lot of episodes, behind the scenes or something) that you could [edit] in? Even a link to said Lorre interviews would improve this post.

Comment: OP already left a comment on the question two years ago indicating that *The Misinterpretation Agitation* was not the first TBBT episode to do this.